# How does "slc start" determine which js should be loaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, package.json

I can not find any detail explain about which property of package.json it looks at.

Normal package.json which have a "main" entry:

`...
"main": "app.js",
...`

OK, it i "slc start" it will load app.js.

But if i remove the "main" entry from package.json (not delete the app.js file), 
the "slc start" still load app.js.

Why? how does slc determine which js should be loaded?

Comment: From the docs: "If not specified, the application in the current working directory is started".
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/NODE/slc+start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "Running an App" (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIS/Running+an+app):

The application must have one of the following in the root directory
(where you're running Arc):

- Main application script file named server.js, app.js, or index.js.
- A package.json file with a main property specifying the main application script file.